# mv: cannot create directory permission denied

Tags: mv

```
:/usr/share/blender/datafiles$ mv "/home/bob/Documents/uncompressed files/filmic-blender-master" /usr/share/blender/datafiles
mv: cannot create directory '/usr/share/blender/datafiles/filmic-blender-master': Permission denied
```

So basically... I don't know what's wrong. and I have  been googaling for an hour.
It dose not help that I can't find any examples of a file being moved from one long directory path to another long directory path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error because your account doesn't have permission to write to the directory where you are trying to move the file.  The space in `/usr/share` is system-wide space.  It's not owned or writable by a normal account.

You can run the command in a elevated mode using `sudo`.  This will make the command have the effect of being run by the superuser (root).

Run this command instead:

```
$ sudo mv "/home/bob/Documents/uncompressed files/filmic-blender-master" /usr/share/blender/datafiles/
```

**Note**
*I added a trailing slash "/".  It isn't required.  But it's a safe guide to avoid mistakenly moving a file into a file instead of a directory.  If you misspell the target directory you could loose your file by writing to a file by that name instead.*

Comment: Thank you "L. D. James".
I really try not to post stupid questions on sites like these.
But some times my ignorance is inescapable. And I don't have a friend who is a learned Linux user, to lean on for even small things like these.
Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: That's what we are here for.  This is a tip that will help you excel faster.  Try to be descriptive in your topic title.  When you take the time to pick a good title, many times the answer will come to you while you are studying your question.  The title should have included something about the content.  The content was an error related to permission.  Having good titles will get you quicker answers as well as give you much more technical insight, without even trying.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!